# Is this a "new" terminology in homology/cohomology theory?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

I have the following question. For our research purpose, we have introduced the following concept:

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a continuous, disrecte and open mapping between two locally compact metric spaces. For each $x\in X$, denote by $U(x,r)$ the component of $x$ in $f^{-1}(B(f(x),r))$.

Fix $x_0\in X$ and $y_0=f(x_0)$, $r>0$. We say a map $g:B(y_0,r)\to X$ is a local left homotopy inverse for $f$ at $x_0$ if $g\circ f|_{U(x_0,r)}$ is homotopic to the indentity map on $U(x_0,r)$, via a homotopy $H_t$ such that $x_0\notin H_t(\partial U(x_0,r))$ for all $t\in [0,1]$. Similarly, $g$ is a local right homotopy inverse for $f$ if $f\circ g$ is homotopic to the identity on $B(y_0,r)$ via a homotopy $H_t$ with $y_0\notin H_t(\partial B(y_0,r))$ for all $t\in [0,1]$. If $g$ is a left and right local homotopy inverse, we simply call it a local homotopy inverse of $f$.

Let $\mathcal{B}_f^*$ denote the left homotopy branch set, which means the set of points in $X$ at which $f$ has no left homotopy inverse. Let $\mathcal{B}_f$ denote the branch point of $f$, that is the points at which $f$ is not a local homeomorphism. It is clear that $\mathcal{B}_f^*\subset \mathcal{B}_f$.

Here comes my question:

1. How standard is the concept "local homotopy inverse"? I do not know any reference where similar definition apears.
2. What are the weakest assumption that ensures $\mathcal{B}_f^*=\mathcal{B}_f$? If $X$ and $Y$ are cohomology $n$-manifold, then the standard topological degree theory implies the coincidence. I am interested in more general metric spaces where complicated (co)homology is allowed.

I am very greatful for any possible suggestions and references. Thanks.